# How do we modify a table's column name in Azure SQL Datawarehouse?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there a function to or any expression to modify a column name in Azure SQL datawarehouse.

How do we do it.

Comment: Hi @Tejaswini, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, Azure SQL Data Warehouse doesn't support rename the column name for now.

Others have post this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/18434083-rename-a-column-name-in-sqldw) and it's voted up 153 times, but still with no answer:
[image]

We could create a new table with the new column name, and then copy the data from the old table.

Ref: [CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (Azure SQL Data Warehouse)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7)

There is no function or expression can achieve that in ADW for now.